# How to intercept POST request in TurboGears/repoze.who to invalidate user session when hitting the login_handler url

Tags: python, turbogears2, beaker, repoze.who

For a TurboGears 2 web application, when the login form is submitted it POST's to `/login_handler`. If a user session already exists it will reuse the session id and set that as the cookie. If a session does not exist, it creates a new one. I am trying to intercept or modify the logic for `/login_handler` so that whenever a user POST's to that endpoint and authenticates, if they have a session already it will invalidate it and create a new one, thus giving a new unique session id to increase entropy and attempt to help prevent session fixation. I am testing this with Burp Suite and using the Sequencer to start a live capture and validate the results for the entropy of the session id.

TurboGears 2 uses `repoze.who` and `beaker-py` for authentication and session management. I've delved into the TG2 and repoze.who source code and found references to [FastFormPlugin](https://github.com/TurboGears/tg2/blob/98682e6d5151dcf5792c8e2b9e522b7f7a407cf7/tg/configuration/auth/fastform.py#L20C11-L20C11) and [AuthTktCookiePlugin](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.who/blob/master/repoze/who/plugins/auth_tkt.py) which I believe is what handles the identification/authentication of the `auth_tkt` cookie for the session. I've tried to create my own simple identifier plugin that removes the `environ['HTTP_COOKIE']` value but it still used the old session id.

```py
class TestIdentifier(object):
    def identify(self, environ):
        path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']

        if path_info == "/login_handler":
            query = self._get_form_data(environ)

            try:
                credentials = {'login': query['login'],
                               'password': query['password'],
                               'max_age':query.get('remember')}
            except KeyError:
                credentials = None

            params = {}
            if 'came_from' in query:
                params['came_from'] = query['came_from']

            destination = _build_url(environ, "/post_login", params=params)
            environ['repoze.who.application'] = HTTPFound(location=destination)
            del environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
            return credentials
        elif path_info in ("/login", "/post_login"):
            query = self._get_form_data(environ)
            environ['repoze.who.logins'] = 0

        return None

    def _get_form_data(self, environ):
        request = Request(environ)
        query = dict(request.GET)
        query.update(request.POST)
        return query
```

I have also attempted a [TurboGears application wrapper](https://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/turbogears/hooks.html#application-wrappers) but the wrapper is never called when the `/login_handler` endpoint is hit, even when other endpoints are making their way into the wrapper.

```py
class TestWrapper(ApplicationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, handler, config):
        super(TestWrapper, self).__init__(handler, config)

    def __call__(self, controller, environ, context):
        if context.request.path.startswith("/login_handler"):
            logging.info("I am never called")
        return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
```

TLDR; I'd like to be able to access the current turbogears session when the `/login_handler` is hit and invalidate the user session and get a new session id.